# Allow point delete in polygon drawing mode

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm working on a project with Mapbox and I want to customize how I draw the polygon, basically I want to allow point delete on button click and keep in drawing mode.I implemented the behavior, but the point does not get deleted.

I appreciate your help!

```
var description = "<button id='popup'> Button</button>"

function handlePop(coords) {
    var feature = { type: 'Point', coordinates: coords };
    draw.delete(feature);
}

let point = 0;
map.on('click', () => {
    const coords = draw.getAll().features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];

    if (point) {
        new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeButton: false })
            .setLngLat(coords[point])
            .setHTML(description)
            .addTo(map);

        document.getElementById('popup').addEventListener('click', handlePop(coords[point]));
    }

    point++;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the draw built-in delete point feature. To activate it you should pass `trash: true` parameter.

```
 let draw = new MapboxDraw({
    controls: {
      polygon: true,
      trash: true
    }
  });

  map.addControl(draw);
```